# Maximo Anywhere 7.5.2, Label issue

Tags: maximo-anywhere

In Maximo Anywhere 7.5.2, Label "My Assgined Work" in WO listing header it dispalying as "getMyAssginedWork" in the UI screen. Can you help me to solve this, In artifact.js also label is "My Assgined Work". but the label is coming from below querybase from name="getMyAssignedWork",                             Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Are you using admin mode or not?  If you are intending to use admin mode, make sure that you've loaded the query information into the Maximo server using the Admin Config Loader tool in our documentation.